# Por qué hasOwnProperty retorna false con prototype?

Tags: javascript

```js
function A() {

this.name = 'Eduardo';

}

A.prototype.edad = 17;

var b = new A();

console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("edad"));
```

Yo sabia que el `prototipo`, agregaba la `propiedad`, entonces como es?, por qué `false`?

Answer (score 4):

Porque `hasOwnProperty` no considera las propiedades heredadas (vía cadena de prototype).

Ver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

creo que no funciona con prototypes: mira segun https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty hay ejemplos :

```js
o = new Object();
o.prop = 'exists';
o.hasOwnProperty('prop');             // returns true
o.hasOwnProperty('toString');         // returns false
o.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty');   // returns false
```

ahora modificando un poco tu codigo:

```js
function A() {

this.name = 'Eduardo';

}

var b = new A();

b.edad = 17;


console.log(b.hasOwnProperty('edad'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hablando técnicamente `hasOwnProperty` busca la propiedad en
>   `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` , si existe y es enumerable
>   entonces devuelve `true` de lo contrario `false`

Todos los objetos heredan
el prototipo `Object.prototype`

Para tenerlo más claro

```
var x = {}
Object.getPrototypeOf(x) == Object.prototype // devuelve true
```

Con una funcion

```
   function y() {}
   Object.getPrototypeOf(y) == Function.prototype // devuelve true
   Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) == Object.prototype // devuelve true
```

`y` hereda las propiedades declaradas en `Function.prototype`, pero `Function.prototype` hereda todas las propiedades declaradas en `Object.prototype`, por tanto `y` hereda las propiedades de ambos.

Puede resultar tedioso la sintaxis 
`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` establecido por la `W3C` por lo que la mayoría de navegadores crean un shortcut para acceder a él, es el famoso `__proto__`, No obstante `__proto__` no es estándar por lo que si no está disponible basta hacer lo siguiente

```
if (!Object.prototype.__proto__) 
  {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, '__proto__', {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        get : function(){
            return Object.getPrototypeOf(this)
        }
    })  
  }
```

Ahora basta hacer `obj.__proto__` para obtener el prototipo de un objeto.

Para entender `hasOwnProperty` primero hay que entender la `cadena de prototipado`

Cuando tu accedes a una `propiedad` de algún objeto, primero se busca dicha elemento en tu `definición` del `objeto`, si no existe, entonces se procede a buscar en el `prototipo`, si no está en el `prototipo` se busca en el `prototipo` del `prototipo` y así sucesivamente.

Para verlo más claro haremos uso de `Object.create`, el cuál crea un objecto con el prototipo especificado, en lugar de `Object.prototype`

```
z = Object.create(null, {'foo' : { value: 'foo', enumerable: true } }) 
// devuelve {foo : "foo"}
z.hasOwnProperty // devuelve undefined
z.hasOwnProperty('foo') // Lanza excepcion
```

`z` no tiene como prototipo `Object.prototype` por tanto no podemos usar `hasOwnProperty`, y por eso la excepción al querer ejecutar dicho método

> si has prestado la suficiente antención has de deducir rápido que
>   podemos simular `hasOwnProperty` con
>   `(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(z)['foo'] != undefined) 
>    && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(z)['foo'].enumerable`
>   no te desilusiones si no lo deduciste, es un tema un tanto complejo.

Ahora si recordamos la definición

> Hablando técnicamente
>   `hasOwnProperty` busca la propiedad en
>   `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` , si existe y es enumerable
>   entonces devuelve `true` de lo contrario `false`

¿Qué pasa si no es enumerable ?

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__').enumerable // false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') // false 
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.prototype, 'hasOwnProperty').enumerable // true 
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty') // true
```

Como puedes ver, son dos requisos para que hasOwnProperty devuelve `true`, primero que sea una propiedad definida en el mismo objeto (no en prototipos) y segundo que sea `enumerable`

Comment: Que te refieres con enumerable